# DeviceMotion on Android Chrome

Tags: android, google-chrome, device, sensors, motion

Is there some kind of prefix for the JavaScript DeviceMotionEvent in the Chrome browser for Android?

Firefox Mobile supports it, but Chrome doesn't (tested on Xperia S and Nexus 4).
Here's the code i use:

```
if (window.DeviceMotionEvent) {
    window.addEventListener('devicemotion', deviceMotionHandler, false);
} else {
    $( "#divid" ).text( "DeviceMotion NOT supported" );
}
```

Chrome Version: 29.0.1547.72
Firefox Version: 24.0
Android Version: 4.3 (Nexus 4) and 4.1 (Xperia S)

PS: DeviceOrientationEvent is working well in Chrome and Firefox Mobile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found a way to get it to work:

I downloaded the Beta Version of Chrome (30.0.1599.81) for Android.
The DeviceMotion event is supported there.